# Unable to move data from HDFS to Cassndra( different server)

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, hive, sqoop

I am trying to move my data (exported from Hive) to a Cassandra table located in some other server
This is sqoop command :

```
export --connect  jdbc:cassandra://server_address:port/KeySpace_name  --username "MyUsername"--password "MyPass"  --table my_cassandra_table --export-dir /user/xyz/ --columns Column_list
```

I get this error:

E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, Call From trphada05.hadoop.searshc.com/157.241.81.9 to trphada01:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused